# Is there a way to temporarily disable [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] when using IDatabaseInitilizer

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am building a new database, using Code-First in EF 6.xx

I have my model ID's decorated with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`

I.E

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid ID { get; set; }
```

Now, this works great when running in normal circumstances, however, in my database seeding I need to populate the new database with some existing data and therefore need to force an ID for the duration of the seeding.

To do this, I commented out the attribute on the models and at the end of the seeding I call

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE " + tableName + " ADD  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [ID]");
```

This puts the default back on, and can be seen working when you enter a new row directly in the database - however, when you add an entity to the database in code the ID becomes `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` - showing me that the database is not generating the Guid.

Now - I could leave the attribute commented out, seed my database and then go back into the models and remove the comment - though this becomes a pain, especially when there are a bunch of them i need to do.

so - is there a way to disable, or ignore, the attribute (in code) and then re-enable it in the IDatabaseInitializer?